# Rails webserver crashing after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

So coming from ruby 2.4.6 to ruby 2.7.2 and rails 4.2.8 to rails 5, I upgraded my app and tested it locally, now im trying to deploy to heroku, the web server crashes as soon as its done deploying.

The web server logs have the following:

```
2020-10-26T11:37:57.946836+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:256:in `app'
2020-10-26T11:37:57.946836+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:131:in `load_and_bind'
2020-10-26T11:37:57.946836+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:501:in `run'
2020-10-26T11:37:57.946837+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:171:in `run'
2020-10-26T11:37:57.946837+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'
2020-10-26T11:37:57.946837+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.0.2/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2020-10-26T11:37:57.946837+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2020-10-26T11:37:57.946837+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
2020-10-26T11:37:58.074574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-26T11:37:58.109882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The build log has the following

```
-----> Detecting rails configuration
###### WARNING:
       Your app was upgraded to bundler 2.1.4.
       Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 1.17.3.
       
       If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues
       
###### WARNING:
       Detecting rails configuration failed
       set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> release, web, worker
       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 387.5M
-----> Launching...
```

What could be the culprit?

Comment: `set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug`
Add that environment variable with that value and star the build process again. Also share your `Gemfile` as well as any other relevant ruby files.

Answer (score 0):

Try `heroku logs` command after you pushed a deploy, and you'll see more detailed errors messages.